# docker-compose not showing in netstat

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I starting docker-compose everything is working but netstat doesn't show exposed port. Sometimes after changing port number it's working.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: app_nginx
    environment:
      PHP_DOCKER_HOST: "app_php"
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/
    networks:
      - net
    depends_on:
      - php

  php:
    container_name: app_php
    build:
      context: php
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/
    networks:
      - net
    extra_hosts:
      - "docker_host:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"

networks:
  net:
    name: ${NETWORK_NAME}
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: ${NETWORK_SUBNET}
```

sudo netstat -nlp

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
```

Can anyone help me?

System: Windows 10, Wsl2 system: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Did you confirm that the app is running? Any chance the container crashed?

Comment: I've checked and app is running